# codeigniter page loading error my_loader

Tags: codeigniter

On my MY_Loader for codeigniter. I gave it another go I have got one part worked out I have worked out how to get the front end url defined

**But can not seem to get the admin one done.**

It throws the fire fox page load error.

`The page isn't redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.`

In the **HTTP_SERVER** area you will see I have tried both options getting base url and other.

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* load the MX_Loader class */
require APPPATH."third_party/hmvc/loader.php";

class MY_Loader extends MX_Loader {

 public function __construct() {

     // Backend url calling not working.

     // Tried But no luck. 
     $SERVER_URL = config_item('base_url');
     $HTTP_SERVER = explode('/', $SERVER_URL);
     $admin = end($HTTP_SERVER);
     $myLastElement = end($HTTP_SERVER);
     $admin = str_replace("/admin","",$SERVER_URL);
     define('HTTP_SERVER', $admin);

     // Tried But no luck.
     define('HTTP_SERVER', config_item('base_url'));


     // Working Gets front main.
     $CATALOG_URL = config_item('base_url');
     $HTTP_CATALOG = explode('/', $CATALOG_URL);
     $myLastElement = end($HTTP_CATALOG);
     $home = str_replace("admin/","",$CATALOG_URL);

     define('HTTP_CATALOG', $home);

      $this->_ci_view_paths = array(APPPATH . 'views/template/' => TRUE);
      $this->_ci_ob_level  = ob_get_level();
      $this->_ci_library_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
      $this->_ci_helper_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH);
      $this->_ci_model_paths = array(APPPATH);

      log_message('debug', "MY_Loader Class Initialized");
   }  
}
```

Comment: The error you're getting "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting" is a Firefox error. Have you tried to clear the browser cache & cookies?

Comment: Yes nothing happened same.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You have defined HTTP_SERVER, twice.

Comment: Because I have multi sub directory codeigniter system. From my experience it best and easer to set it up way I am doing it.

Answer (score 0):

On my dashboard I did not have it set correct for session check think it was conflict. I can now seem to use this OK define('HTTP_SERVER', config_item('base_url')); will do more testing though on MY_loader.php.

**New**

```
public function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
$this->load->library('user');
$this->lang->load('english', 'english');
$this->lang->load('common/dashboard', 'english');
        if($this->session->userdata('user_id')) {
return true;
} else {
return false;
redirect('login');
}
}
```

**OLD**

```
public function __construct(){
parent::__construct();
$this->load->library('user');
$this->lang->load('english', 'english');
$this->lang->load('common/dashboard', 'english');
if($this->session->userdata('user_id') == false) {

if (array_key_exists('warning', $this->error)) {
$data['error_warning'] = "Session Has Expired Please Login";
} else {
$data['error_warning'] = '';
}

redirect('login');

return !$error;
}
}
```